# What is the 統 in 傳統？

Tags: etymology

The 傳 in 傳統 is easy to understand. Tradition is transmitted. As the dictionary(MOE) says: 世代相傳.

But what about the 統？It has many meanings, including verbal ones.

- One (絲的頭緒) refers to the main thread of silk. So is 傳統 the essential, important part of transmission?
- Another says: 相繼不絕的體系、關係。如：「血統」. So is it the uninterrupted transmission?
- A third one says: 綱要, the essentials, similar to my first guess.

Comment: cf. bkrs：统 名
I b.f.
1) order; system (系统)
 
（事物间连续的关系） interconnected system:
系统 system; genealogy
血统 blood relationship; blood lineage
体统 decorum; decency

Answer (score 1):

A phrase you'll often hear is: "It's a tradition in our family."

Now extend family to 民族

The word tradition comes from: trans 过 + dare 送给 (Originally in the sense of Jewish instruction, Mosaic Law, it seems.)

传统: 传承血统 pass on bloodline

Whereby, 血统 does not just indicate the dna I think, but all the idiosyncrasies that come with it, the dances, the funny hats, the strange and wonderful delicacies, the social expressions of that bloodline.